# Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5): Error : Out of memory

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, asp.net-core-3.1

We have Azure DevOps build pipeline for our ASP.NET Core app, where we get from time to time this error in the build step:

```
...
##[error]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.1.410\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5): Error : Out of memory.
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.1.410\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5): error : Out of memory. [D:\a\1\s\Web\App.WebApi\App.WebApi.csproj]
```

This is our pipeline definition.

```
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects
  value: '**/App.WebApi.csproj'
- name: BuildParameters.TestProjects
  value: '**/*App.Tests.Unit/*.csproj'
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/development
    - refs/heads/master
  paths:
    include:
    - Web/App.WebApi
    - Libraries
    - Web/App.Web.Framework
    - App.Tests.Unit
    - Libraries/App.Core
    - Libraries/App.Services
    - Libraries/App.Data
    exclude:
    - Libraries/Tfs
    - Libraries/SomeService
  batch: True
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/development
jobs:
- job: Phase_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2019
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: Use .Net Core sdk 3.1.x
    inputs:
      version: 3.1.410
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      feedRestore: 50ad9938-c030-4dc7-8391-5b3138b77ae5
  - task: gitversion/setup@0
    displayName: gitversion/setup
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 5.x
  - task: gitversion/execute@0
    displayName: gitversion/execute
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)  -p:Version=$(GitVersion.SemVer)
      workingDirectory: Web/App.WebApi
...
```

What could be the reason for this error, as this happens sometimes e.g., every 8th or 10th build ?

Comment: Without knowing your code it is super hard to find the problem. We had this in the past because of not cleaning up resources while unit testing (static properties without .Dispose()) So "sometimes" it failed.

Comment: Yes in unit testing that could happen, but cannot be the case during the build, as Dispose() is used only in runtime.

Comment: Of course, my fault. Maybe its worth trying to build on a hosted linux (ubuntu image) machine?